# perl compilation is opening some manual page

Tags: perl

I have been compiling simple perl5 program in bash by typing: perl  but output is comming like this:

```
=over 8

=item atan2 Y,X
ATAN2 ARCTANGENT TAN TANGENT

Returns the arctangent of Y/X in the range -PI to PI.

For the tangent operation, you may use the MATH::TRIG::TAN
function, or use the familiar relation:

    sub tan { sin($_[0]) / cos($_[0])  }

The return value for ATAN2(0,0) is implementation-defined; consult
your atan2(3) manpage for more information.

=back
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger :-) It's probably your perl script which contains the error, not the error message. Maybe it's a good idea to post your script too?

Comment: sorry i am new to perl.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put your source code in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the output of running `perldoc -f atan2`:

```
atan2 Y,X
    Returns the arctangent of Y/X in the range -PI to PI.

    For the tangent operation, you may use the "Math::Trig::tan"
    function, or use the familiar relation:

        sub tan { sin($_[0]) / cos($_[0])  }

    The return value for "atan2(0,0)" is implementation-defined;
    consult your atan2(3) manpage for more information.

    Portability issues: "atan2" in perlport.
```

You must be running something which dumps the POD.